# ASP.NET Core wait for all other threads before starting transaction

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-core

I need to perform several task (recalculates) on one table with EF Core. When this calculation starts, no other transaction should start.
Is this possible to achieve with `Database.BeginTransactionAsync`/`TransactionScope`?

Something like this:

- Thread 1 starts.
- Thread 1 enter transaction
- Thread 1 execute select statement
- Thread 2 starts.
- Thread 2 enter transaction (and wait!!)
- Thread 1 do some job (thread 2 is waiting)
- Thread 1 do some queries (thread 2 is waiting)
- Thread 1 save changes to one table (thread 2 is waiting)
- Thread 1 ends transaction (this will continue executing code on thread 2)
- Thread 2 code runs

I see four possible ways to do that, but options 1, 2 and 4 doesn't work:

1. `DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction`  (if 2 methods (2 calls to API) calls this, second should wait)
2. `new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)` (if 2 methods (2 calls to API) calls this, second should wait)
3. Create some static variable and use `lock(static_variable)`
4. Lock table, but it is not working

Any lock on database/table would be better, because this ensures also work done in Management studio for example. I also tried:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT top 1 1 FROM [Transactions] WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)
```

but I could call `select` in other management studio, so table was not locked.